# Dropping image to a div removes it from the previous div

Tags: javascript

I have made this

https://jsfiddle.net/a4376mr8/

When I drag and drop the image div to a new div, why is it not there in the previous div?

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const imageBox = document.querySelector('#draggableItem');
for (const box of boxes) {
    box.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className += ' onhover';

    })
    box.addEventListener('dragleave', function () {
        this.className = 'box';

    })
    box.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
        this.className = 'box';
        this.append(imageBox);
    })
}
```

Comment: It's not there in the previous div because `this.append` will move the element to the new location (as the exact same element cannot exist simultaneously in two different places in the DOM). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your needs, that the image be repeated on drag and drop, you need to clone your div tag dom object. Since js just sees the reference to it, when you simply append it, this causes it to just move from place to place instead of duplicating.

So instead of just appending, clone the node as follows (line 15 of your fiddle's js).

```
this.append(imageBox.cloneNode(true));
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4376mr8/1/